# What is the origin of multi-line change log entries?

Tags: history, patch, version-control

Being able to dig into software history and find a proper justification for the code is *great*.

I think I first saw these in Linux patches - pre-source control.  Obviously when Git was written, it supported patch descriptions.  But before Git, systems like Subversion or CVS were written with single-line messages in mind.

Are there other influences we can trace this to, or did it mainly came out of Linux development?

Comment: It seems you haven't actually used CVS or Subversion. They both support multi-line commit messages.

Comment: I cannot speak for older `SCCS` versions, since there does not seem to be source code available, but `SCCSv4`, first published February 18, 1977 supports multi line delta comments. So multi line delta comments have been at least in use 28 years before git. Given that the announcement for `SCCSv4` does not mention multi line comments, it is higly probable that you can add another 5 years for `SCCSv1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RCS predates Linux, supports multi-line change-comments (I've been using that feature since 1988).  CVS inherited that from RCS.  rcs2log has been around since 1992, rendering RCS logs -- including multiline comments.

RCS's **`ci`** prompts for a change-comment with zero or more lines ending with a line containing only a **`.`** (like mail).  I've been using rcs2log since 2003 to format the RCS logs into readable changelogs such as that for [`ded`](http://invisible-island.net/ded/ded/CHANGES.html).

By the way, SCCS also supports multi-line comments, but I found it less user-friendly in that regard when I began using it in early in 1986 (see [discussion](https://invisible-island.net/ded/sccs_tools.html#resources-frontend)).

One aspect of multi-line change-comments which appears to have been overlooked is *entering* them and possibly *revising* them.  The oldest version of CVS which you might find (1.3 in April 1992) used a text editor for this purpose.  The feature is in all subsequent releases of CVS.  You can browse the sources [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/cvs/ccvs/), or check-out a [readonly](https://savannah.nongnu.org/cvs/?group=cvs) copy.  It seems that the repository starts at the end of November 1994, which was between 1.3 and 1.4 (1.5 was released in July 1995).  To see 1.3, you'd have to get a tarball.

Linus was certainly aware of it, because the first request reflected in BitKeeper's change-history was for this feature:

```
commit e1dc29195bd72a9a4c8f1e817e08b8c0358ee88b
Author: Larry McVoy <lm@bitkeeper.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 31 23:29:46 2002 -0800

    Add a bk comment interface so that Linus can edit the comments after
    the fact.

    bk: 3c5a43eabhI7oSce6C4ms5U-kIcEv
```

To see what was implemented, you might want to read through the [source-code](https://www.bitkeeper.org/download.html).  Here's a little bit from a change about a month later (this one's change-comment hints that the initial solution was not satisfactory):

```
+/*
+ * Prompt the user with a set of comments, returning
+ * 0 if they want to use them,
+ * -1 for an error or an abort.
+ */
+int
+comments_prompt(char *file)
+{
+       char    buf[10];
+       extern  char *editor;
+
+       unless (editor || (editor = getenv("EDITOR"))) editor = "vi";
+       while (1) {
+               printf("\n-------------------------------------------------\n");
+               fflush(stdout);
+               if (cat(file)) return (-1);
+               printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
+               printf("Use these comments: (e)dit, (a)bort, (u)se? ");
```

Then again, the question asked about ***origin***.  I recall that [DEC CMS](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c04622623) (predating CVS 1.3) provided its information in full-screen (terminal) mode.  I used that in the 1988-1989 time frame.  However, Git's **origin** goes through CVS, and in turn CVS may have been original (in the sense that there was no influence from exposure to earlier tools), or it may not.

Comment: Git also has a convention that the first line is a self-contained summary (and people have standards about maximum line length).  E.g. this is used in git web interfaces, gitk, `git rebase -i` and `git log --pretty=short`.  I suspect this is what I was half-remembering (and utterly failed in researching). I wonder if a convention like this was leveraged in any tool in SVN or earlier software.

Comment: Back in the days SCSS was pretty successful, but it was commercial. RCS was created as a free alternative to SCSS, but with much less functionality. The first versions of CVS were just wrappers around RCS commands, and subsequent versions still depended on it for a long time.  IIRC it was ~1992 that CVS became completely self-contained.

Comment: RCS was definitely a commercial product that you had to buy. This canged in 1990.